# ERROR in node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1196,54): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, fullcalendar

I'm trying to run `npm run build` in my project but I'm facing this error :

```
ERROR in node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1196,54): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1197,34): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1197,45): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1198,17): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1199,34): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1199,51): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1199,64): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1200,28): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1200,54): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1200,89): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1201,24): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1201,33): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1202,20): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1203,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1203,32): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1204,25): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1204,31): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1205,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1206,30): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1206,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1207,35): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1207,54): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1208,32): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1208,38): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1209,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1209,30): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1210,31): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1210,47): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1210,53): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(1214,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.d.ts(2698,27): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

I tried to change the version of my typescript but the project want a version lower than the 2.8 and greater than 2.7. So the error persists.
Could someone help me solve it?

Comment: it appears to be an issue with fullcalendar.  have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your "typeRoots" in your tsconfig files
probably it has some other addresses that is not supposed to check.
should be

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

also try removing `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and run
`npm i`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue where my [package-lock.json](https://www.mariokandut.com/what-is-package-lock-json/) wasn't checked into source control. My build server would try to restore the modules but grabbed the wrong version which led to this issue.

Comment: How did you solve it? Probably I have a similar issue but can't find a solution for it.

Comment: @D.Zet There is a packge-lock.json file in your project directory. Make sure it is checked into source control so that your local machine and build server share the file. Your local npm should add the appropriate dependency resolution to this file.